# Can't remove objects from ManyToMany relations

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have created a new field on my User model.

```
blocked_users = models.ManyToManyField('self', verbose_name=_('blocked users'),
                                       symmetrical=False, 
                                       related_name='blocked_by',
                                       blank=True)
```

So, I wanna get blocked users:

```
In [18]: User.objects.first().blocked_users.all()
Out[18]: <UserQuerySet [<User: admin>, <User: test@mail.com>, <User: i_uglev>, <User: denisdvornikov6697>]
```

Now, I clear that and try again:

```
In [21]: User.objects.first().blocked_users.clear()
In [22]: User.objects.first().blocked_users.all()
Out[22]: <UserQuerySet [<User: admin>, <User: test@mail.com>, <User: i_uglev>, <User: denisdvornikov6697>]>
```

I tried doing it from django-admin and got the same result. What's wrong?

Comment: what does this returns  User.objects.first().blocked_users.remove()

Comment: None, I see nothing.